# Migrate Oracle partitioned tables to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, partitioning, sql-server-migration-assi

I need to migrate about 700 Oracle partitioned tables (RANGE and LIST partitioning) to SQL Server.
Turns out the SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant) does not handle Oracle partitioned tables (this is the official answer I got from Microsoft).

Any tool / script / other suggestion to automate this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are correct: 
Tried to do this for a project last year for work and found out the same thing:
Tried doing a little research on google to see if things have changed but found out the following:

Migration of Oracle Partitioned Tables is not supported by SSMA. Partitioned tables are migrated as a Non-partitioned simple tables.

Partitioning of the these Tables in SQL server is required to be done manually as per the physical database architecture planning and logical drives of the server system.

Any partition maintenance (adding or dropping or truncating the partitions) related code need to be re-rewritten in SQL Server."

Comment: Thanks for confirming my findings. So - Any 3rd party tool / script / other suggestion to automate this process? Should I wish to do this myself I assume I would simply take the Oracle HIGH_VALUE as the SQL Server partition boundary value with RANGE RIGHT for RANGE partitions, and use the Oracle LIST value with  RANGE LEFT for single-value LIST partitioning. Not sure how to handle multi-valued LIST partitioning...

Comment: i would suggest writing a java program which will create these jobs for you to automate the process. just google your question and write this job program in java. and then have sql server dynamically create these partitions for you.